# How can I use VBA to check the box next to a Pivot Table field to show the field in the table?

Tags: excel, vba, field, pivot-table, fieldlist

I was hoping I could use a code like this:
    `Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Name").Visible = True`
But it is not working. I keep getting the error: "Run-time Error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method.

Simply, I want to check a specific box next to the field name in the pivot table field list. Any idea how I could go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PivotTable.AddFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837987(v=office.15).aspx) method

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddFields("Name")
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly